# Are php resources passed by reference?

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I discovered today that in addition to objects and primitives, PHP has [*resources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). The documentation states that by default [php passes names by value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference). But we know that in PHP 5, [objects are referenced by handle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php), and so while the handle is passed by value, you can treat the handles as references themselves, neatly avoiding the question.

But what about *resources*? Are they, like objects, just handles to be treated as references themselves, or are they actually values that get copied when they're passed?

For example:

```
/**
 * Close the ftp connection and throw an exception.
 *
 * @hack Because php doesn't have a `finally` statement,
 *       we workaround it to make sure the ftp connection is closed.
 * @param resource $conn FTP Buffer
 * @param Exception $e
 */
function ftpCloseWithException($conn, $e) {
    ftp_close($conn); // <-- Is this the same FTP Buffer resource or a new one?
    throw $e;
}
/**
 * Copy the README file from ftp.mozilla.org or do something equally arbitrary using ftp.
 */
function getMozReadme() {
    try {
        $conn = ftp_connect('ftp.mozilla.org');
        …
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        ftpCloseWithException($conn, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: resources are always pass by reference

Comment: Resources are references

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resource is not the actual connection. A resource is nothing more than a pointer to a connection. So when you close the connection belonging to this resource, there is no difference in behavior if it was original or a copied one.

Comment: Saying "it does not matter" doesn't answer the question or specify the behavior.

Comment: In this context saying it does not matter does not mean 'I don't care'. It means there is no difference in behavour between them. I will edit the text

Answer (score 8):

No they are **not** passed by reference by default, they are handled as any other PHP variable in this case. Check this example:

```
function test($fd) {
    $fd = NULL;
}

$fd = fopen('/tmp/test', 'w+');
test($fd);
var_dump(is_resource($fd)); // bool(true);
```

... but it's by the nature of resources they point to a *single* outer resource. This can be a file, a database connection or something like this. So any operations on a resource (or a copy of it) would have direct effect on that *single* outer resource.

Check this example:

```
function close($fd) {
    fclose($fd);
}

$fd = fopen('/tmp/test', 'w+');
close($fd);
var_dump(is_resource($fd)); // bool(false);
```

In the above example, the PHP engine resets the **all** references to $fd in all scopes after the files has been closed. This means from the sight of this side effect they may not being exactly the *same* as other variables.

Comment: To be precise, nothing is passed by reference by default in PHP.

Comment: @PEMapModder Not true, objects are passed byref.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac You can't really pass objects in PHP at all. You can only pass object references. And object references aren't passed by references by default. Compare `function f(&$o){ $o=new stdclass; }` and `function f($o){ $o = new stdclass; }`

Comment: @NinoŠkopac and in this sense, you are actually passing the object reference, which is similar to a resource reference. You are still working on the same ultimately underlying data, but passing a `&$object` is like passing the reference of something by reference. Meanwhile, you can't double-reference variables in PHP, i.e. `function f(&$a) { $a = "b"; } $b =& $c; f($b);` still modifies `$c`, but if `$b = $object;`, the real $object will not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

A resource is neither an object nor a variable. It is just a **resource**. Basically what this means is that you do not really interact with resources the way you could do with, say an object. The PHP documentation itself says:

*"As resource variables hold special handlers to opened files, database connections, image canvas areas and the like, converting to a resource makes no sense."*

Basically unless say you are working on the core Zend Engine or creating extensions for PHP like PECL, you would really worry much about resource. From a PHP coding stamp point the only time we do stuff on resources is say to check if a database connection attempt returned `NULL or a resource`

You have a function called `get_resource_type()` which returns the `type` of resource like say "file" for the return of an `fopen()` function but it is just a named identifier and nothing much to work out off..

Comment: @raidenance: "the only time we do stuff on resources" that part does not make a lot of sense. File operation, external connections, etc all use resources.

Comment: @nvanesch: What I meant by that part is when we do operations on the resource directly like say `if($myResource=="<something>")...`

Comment: A ok, now i understand. I thought you meant things like `fopen($fileResource, "Foo");` were barely used