# Is it possible to register some callback function to free resources after a curl request has finished?

Tags: php, curl, logging, resources, file-handling

For some library I want to add a curl debug function which may be called in certain situations. However I stumbled upon some issue with freeing resources.

This is my library function:

```
/**
 * @param $curlhandle: The curlhandle resource which was created by curl_init();
 * @param null $log_location: Log location folder. If empty the wp-content directory will be used.
 * @param string $log_file_name: The name of the logfile to be written.
 */
function cis_curl_add_debug($curlhandle, $log_location = null, $log_file_name = "cis-curl-errorlog.txt") {

    if(!is_resource($curlhandle)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect call to cis_curl_add_debug function: Expected curl handle.",E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    }

    if (!$log_location) {
        $log_folder = realpath(WP_CONTENT_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logs');
        if(!is_dir($log_folder)) {
            mkdir($log_folder,776);
        }
    }

    $fp = fopen($log_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $log_file_name, 'w');
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

    return $curlhandle;
}
```

This is a usage example:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json');

    $ch = cis_curl_add_debug($ch);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Well this should basically work beside of one little fact: The $fp filepointer is never closed with `fclose()`. This means that the log file is locked for writing and if I call t his function multiple times the logfile is not available for writing (or if any other application wants to).

So my idea was to register some function - ***pseudocode***:

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK, function () use ($fp) {
    fclose($fp);
}
```

However I did not find such a possibility yet. Maybe there is a way more obvious solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the handle `$ch` is acted upon by reference you do not need to return the handle. You could choose to have the function do just a little more:

```
function cis_curl_add_debug($curlhandle, $log_location = null, $log_file_name = "cis-curl-errorlog.txt") {

    if(!is_resource($curlhandle)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect call to cis_curl_add_debug function: Expected curl handle.",E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    }

    if (!$log_location) {
        $log_folder = realpath(WP_CONTENT_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logs');
        if(!is_dir($log_folder)) {
            mkdir($log_folder,776);
        }
    }

    $fp = fopen($log_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $log_file_name, 'w');
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

    $result = curl_exec($curlhandle);

    fclose($fp);

    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json');

$result = cis_curl_add_debug($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

Note:

You may wish to rename your function as well to signal the execution of CURL.

This post explains my basis of using `$ch` in the way I did: [Are php resources passed by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16320493/2191572)

Comment: Good solution +1. I have posted how I finally solved it with respect to your useful input.

Comment: @Blackbam Nice, I'm glad you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it finally:

```
 /**
 * Performs a curl_exec with debug output to a specified file.
 *
 * @param &$curlhandle: The curlhandle resource which was created by curl_init(); to be passed by reference
 * @param null $log_location: Log location folder. If empty the wp-content directory will be used.
 * @param string $log_file_name: The name of the logfile to be written.
 * @return bool|resource|void: The result of the curl request
 */
function cis_curl_exec_debug(&$curlhandle, $log_folder = null, $log_file_name = "cis-curl-errorlog.txt") {
    $fp = cis_curl_add_debug($curlhandle,$log_folder,$log_file_name);
    $result = curl_exec($curlhandle);
    fclose($fp);
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Adds debug output to a curl handle before it is executed.
 *
 * NOTE: You have to close the file handle which is returned. The use of cis_curl_exec_debug is recommended for most situations.
 *
 * @param &$curlhandle: The curlhandle resource which was created by curl_init(); to be passed by reference
 * @param null $log_location: Log location folder. If empty the wp-content directory will be used.
 * @param string $log_file_name: The name of the logfile to be written.
 * @return bool|resource|void: The log file resource
 */
function cis_curl_add_debug(&$curlhandle, $log_folder = null, $log_file_name = "cis-curl-errorlog.txt") {

    if(!is_resource($curlhandle)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect call to cis_curl_add_debug function: Expected curl handle.",E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    }

    if (!$log_folder) {
        $log_folder = realpath(WP_CONTENT_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log');
        if(!is_dir($log_folder)) {
            mkdir($log_folder,776);
        }
    }

    $fp = fopen($log_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $log_file_name, 'w');
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

    return $fp;
}
```